# How to handle distributing shared libraries with different compile flags?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am building a shared library which uses compiler flags to load different window manager apis:

```
-DVK_USE_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_KHR
```

and

```
-DVK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR
```

An application is then compiled against the compiled shared library with its on wayland or xcb flag.

What is the standard practice for distributing and loading the compiled library on runtime? Should I produce separate binaries (i.e. `sharedlib.wayland.so` and `sharedlib.xcb.so`), as well as separate executables (i.e. `app.wayland` and `app.xcb`) for each?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just have both, and decide which API to use based on what's available on the user's system or by user settings? I'm not a Linux user, so I don't know much about this.

Comment: Yes, I was considering this! That would mean I'd add #include headers for both APIs for the Linux build, would that be okay?

Comment: Yes, including headers for both and deciding which to use at runtime and deciding which to use at runtime is fine and probably best if you're distributing binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I think you actually want to decide at runtime. But to answer the question you asked:

What it looks like you're doing is creating an abstract interface to any Vulkan window system, and putting different implementations of that interface into their own shared libraries. You have to name the libraries differently, e.g. `libvkwsi-wayland.so`, `libvkwsi-xcb.so`.

Usually, people will have a single executable that decides which implementation to use, and uses `dlopen` to load the corresponding shared library. You then need to use `dlsym` to get function pointers for functions in that library. If you're using C++ and the abstract interface is a literal abstract base class, then your shared libraries would have a single standalone function which creates and returns an instance of a class derived from that abstract class. The application would call that factory function, and from then on could just make virtual function calls into the object like normal.

If you want to directly link against the shared library ("-l" flag at executable link time), then you have to have a separate executable per window system (`myapp-wayland`, `myapp-xcb`, etc.). In that case, you'd probably also want to have a shell or python script that figures out which window system to use and then invokes the right executable -- that way your users don't need to know what window system they should use (fine for advanced users, not so much for most people).

Using separate executables means you're effectively distributing multiple copies of your entire application, even though nearly all of it is probably identical between window systems.